# Free Space Consumed in RDS Mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a mysql hosted as RDS service in AWS.
Total Size consumed by my database i.e., along with table & datas is around 0.01GB

I have executed the query & found the result:

```
SELECT table_schema, 
        ROUND(SUM(data_length+index_length)/1024/1024/1024,2) "size in GB" 
FROM information_schema.tables 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

I am not using binary logs that I become sure by executing the following query

```
SHOW MASTER LOGS;
```

Other log files such as general & error logs are not even consuming 1 MB all together

I have executed the following query to find the InnoDB system tablespace:

```
mysql> SELECT file_name, tablespace_name, table_name, engine, index_length, total_extents, extent_size from information_schema.files WHERE file_name LIKE '%ibdata%';
```

[image]

I have executed the following query to find the InnoDB temporary tablespace:

```
mysql> SELECT file_name, tablespace_name, table_name, engine, index_length, total_extents, extent_size from information_schema.files WHERE file_name LIKE '%ibtmp%';
```

[image]

this temporary file is consuming the space & my free tier is getting exhausted.
Is my table table going to effect if I delete these temporary files?

How can I reduce the space consuming issue except my table data.

Comment: You example queries show 12 MB for both table data and temporary space. That's well below the free tier allotment (which iirc is 30 GB). What you _don't_ show in your question is what makes you think that you're exceeding the allotment.

Comment: I have already crossed 10GB/20GB free tier...Where is the rest of the space?
My log retention period is 0 days..hence no system logs present

Comment: Is this a "normal" RDS instance (ie, not Aurora)? If yes, you pre-allocate your storage space, _whether or not it's used._ Did you take the default value or increase it?

Comment: Every day it is consuming around 0.5GB..How to fix this?

Comment: MySql RDS instance.. I have default 20GB free tier selected at the time of creation... Now its already 10.52GB

Comment: Today is the 17th day of a 31-day month. Multiplying 17/31 by 20 is 10.97, so your current consumption is less than your allowed consumption. This is not a problem.

Comment: What I am worry is that why it has consumed 10GB space already??
If it takes 1Gb or 2GB extra then it was fine...

Comment: As I said earlier, you _pre-allocate_ the amount of storage space. You will be charged for whatever you allocate, and the charges are computed daily. With the default 20 GB of allocated space, you won't exceed the free tier. If it worries you, re-create the database with 15 GB of allocated storage.

Comment: Think of it as an EBS volume, you pay for what you provision, not how much is in it. The growth is just AWS amortizing/distributing daily to show current charges.